# In Firebase Realtime Database when I update values, it returns to old values immediately

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a task reminder app and storing the data in Firebase database under users->userUid->email, username, Tasks. Below Tasks is every task he created. Tasks are named as "Task"+keyTask where keyTask is a random int.

[image]

The problem is whenever I update a task using:

```
EditText titleEditText, descEditText, dateEditText;
DatabaseReference reference;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String oldTitle, oldDesc, oldDate, oldKey;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_task);
    
    
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Tasks");

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    titleEditText = findViewById(R.id.titleUpdate);
    descEditText = findViewById(R.id.descUpdate);
    dateEditText = findViewById(R.id.dateUpdate);

    oldTitle = intent.getStringExtra("titleTask");
    oldDesc = intent.getStringExtra("descTask");
    oldDate = intent.getStringExtra("dateTask");
    oldKey = intent.getStringExtra("keyTask");

    titleEditText.setText(oldTitle);
    dateEditText.setText(oldDate);
    descEditText.setText(oldDesc);
}

public void saveClicked(View view){
    final String newTitle = titleEditText.getText().toString();
    final String newDesc = descEditText.getText().toString();
    final String newDate = dateEditText.getText().toString();
    final String newKey = oldKey;
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("titleTask", newTitle);
    map.put("dateTask", newDate);
    map.put("descTask", newDesc);
    map.put("keyTask", newKey);
    reference.child("Task"+newKey).updateChildren(map);
}
```

I can see that, the database changes the values to the new ones and instantly returns to the old ones again.
Also, when I delete a complete task using removeValue() the database removes it and instantly adds it again by itself. Anyone got any idea what might be happening here?

Comment: It's hard to say more than my initial answer without more information on what you exactly see happening. For example: "I see the database change the values to the new ones and instantly returns to the old ones again." Where do you see this? Are there any other processes that might be running? Did you [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)), and if so: what did it show in the logcat output?

Comment: Where do you see this: exactly where my picture shows, they turn orange, change to new value and instantly return to old values again.                                     Any other process running: Not at all, as you can see it's just a very basic onClick method.

Comment: The cases I've told you are the common cause of this behavior, so it's hard to say any more. Did you enable the debug logging and check its output, as I said in my last comment?

Comment: I'm not sure where should I put the log.i or what should I expect since it doesn't bring up any errors. I've also tried adding OnCompleteListener and check if the task fails, but it doesn't.

Comment: If the completion listener signals that the write was successful, it is indeed not rejected by the security rules. In that case the only cause I can think of for changing the data back is another client perform a write operation. You'll want to search in *that* direction, for example by trying to reproduce the problem in a different part of the database.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your database's security rules are rejecting the update/delete operations. If this happens, the client will briefly show the updated value, before the server tells it that the operation is not allowed.

This is expected behavior, so if you want to prevent it, you'll either have to grant the user access to perform the update/delete, *or* perform the same check as your security rules do in your application code too.

Comment: First thing I did after creating the  database was set the rules to
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

is there anything else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The user id has been update by another user. Kindly check and ensure only that user has access to edit it own page.